# Expression class, change boolean to string compare

Tags: c#, lambda

Our database had IsActive booleans everywhere as a soft delete. We have entity framework blocking all requests with that flag deactivated. We recently changed out database to instead have a statusCode string instead of an IsActive flag.

How would I change the below expression to instead check to see if the StatusCode == "ACTIVE"

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
  var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsActive");
  if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
  {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
    var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, isActiveProperty.PropertyInfo), parameter);
    entityType.QueryFilter = filter;
  }
}
```

I tried changing the types to the following, but it is not working. Lambda's written out this way is throwing me off (Lambda/parameter long form). Somewhere I need to compare (isActivyProperty == "ACTIVE")

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("StatusCode");
    if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(string))
    {
       var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
       var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, isActiveProperty.PropertyInfo), parameter);
       entityType.QueryFilter = filter;//entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);//Update for ef 3.0
    }
}
```

Comment: expression.lambda(expression.equal(expression.property, expression.constant), parameter) ? I can write that long if that isn't sufficient

Comment: Yeah if you could, I think I am close
var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property("StatusCode"), Expression.Constant("ACTIVE")), parameter); but that isn't the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after:

```cs
Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "StatusCode"),
    Expression.Constant("ACTIVE", typeof(string))), parameter);
```

Note: if `FindProperty` returns the member, you may also be able to use it in `Expression.Property` to avoid a second reflection lookup:

```cs
Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, isActiveProperty),
    Expression.Constant("ACTIVE", typeof(string))), parameter);
```

Comment: Your first statement worked exactly as I needed it, thank you! The second gave me an error for isActiveProperty, "Cannot convert IMutableProperty to MethodInfo"

Answer (score 2):

You were generating code like the following for each type;

```cs
.QueryFilter = (p) => p.IsActive;
```

Now you want

```cs
.QueryFilter = (p) => p.StatusCode == "ACTIVE";
```

I find it useful to write the expression I want in C#, then use the debugger to see how the C# compiler turned that into an expression graph. Or look through the static methods on the Expression class and guess what I might need.

In your case you need your lambda body to include the extra equality test and constant value;

```cs
Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(...), Expression.Constant("ACTIVE"))
```

But there are other ways to use the C# compiler to create the `Expression` you want. For example;

```cs
public interface HasStatus {
    StatusCode { get; set; }
}

public static void SetQueryFilter<T>(ModelBuilder builder) where T:HasStatus =>
    builder.Entity<T>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.StatusCode == "ACTIVE");

typeof(...).GetMethod("SetQueryFilter")
    .MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType)
    .Invoke(null, new object[]{ builder });
```

Comment: I 100% agree. Implementing an interface is the cleaner way to do this. Unfortunately we are using entity framework reverse POCO generation to generate the entities and I am unaware of how to add the interface without it getting overwritten when regenerating.

Comment: @ModestMonk you use a second code file - they are generated as `partial class`, which means in a second file, in the same namespace, you can do: `partial class Foo : ISomeInterface {}` - you can also add attributes, methods, etc; all the `partial` framgments are combined (but note: the order is not defined, which sometimes matters for static field initializers)